# Hide console window with Tkinter and cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am using cx_freeze to freeze a tkinter app. When I run the exe I get a wonderfully USELESS console window along with my tkinter GUI.

**I would like to remove/hide this useless black window.**

I've seen threads that suggest the following:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

The above code does the opposite of what I want. It hides my GUI, while the useless black window remains. I would like it to be the other way around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2880316/404469) is very similar, but for wxPython and cx_Freeze. Fortunately, it turns out that the appearance of the console can be configured from the build script, rather than source code. Borrowing from the top two answers, the trick is setting the `base` variable in your cx_Freeze build script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"    # Tells the build script to hide the console.

# <The rest of your build script goes here.>
```

Here is the relevant [documentation](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html) (although it does not explicitly mention that `base` controls the console option).

<sub>Also, just because it's interesting, an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237924/404469) to a different question solves the issue of creating a GUI app with or without a console mode option, which I thought was very cool.</sub>

Comment: This answer works, however you must add base=base in executables= in your setup.py file.  See VICTOR answer below for an example.

Answer (score 14):

I remember reading somewhere that on Windows if you specify your file extension as `.pyw`, it will launch with pythonw.exe (without a console window). Does that work for you?

Comment: Can you try manually launching your program with `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` and see whether that helps?

Comment: It worked for me just changing the extension! (win 7 pro 64x, Python 3.3)
Thanks Noufal Ibrahim

Answer (score 5):

Do exactly just like gary said, then:

```
setup(name="ur package name",
         version="ur package version",
         description="as above",
         executables=[Executable("ur_script.py", base=base)]
```

This will work cx_Freeze

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today

What i was using to compile my python programs was py2exe and the fix was very simple modify the setup file as shown below. My interface is written with Tkinter

modify the "setup.py" py2exe script from:

Old Python Code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['app.py'])
```

New Python Code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['app.py'])
```

After i did this and reran my setup script the application loaded and did not show the console window. The only thing with this is if you have your application sending print commands to the console window you will not see theme. I hope this helps.

Comment: Why doesn't think work for me? I have tried every variation of window / console I could find.

Comment: but the question is about cx_freeze..!!

Answer (score 2):

If using pyinstaller use pyinstaller-gui.py
In Windows command line type

> python pyinstaller-gui.py

This will first say "Please use just 'pyinstaller.py'. Gui is not maintained." Change the code l'il bit and you will be able to run this.

It will show pop up a window to select your script and some checkboxex. Check on 'no console(windows only)

That's it. You are done!

Another option: use --noconsole option while building. i.e:

> python pyinstaller.py --noconsole yourscript.py

Answer (score 2):

For me using the option `--base-name Win32GUI` works. Here is an example:

> cxfreeze your_python_file.py --base-name Win32GUI --target-dir your_target_dir

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "black window" you are referring to the terminal window. In order to disable this from popping up, save your file as a .pyw extension instead of .py