# Hiding the console window

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

**problem**

I started designing GUI applications using Python and Tkinter. When I freeze a script using cxFreeze then when I run that EXE file on a machine. Then first the console window (a black DOS shell in the case of Windows XP) opens and then the main window(Tk() instance) gets initialized.

**goal**

The console window must not appear. Only the Tk() instance should appear.

**code**

```
root = Tk()

Label(root,text="hey").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**specs**

Windows XP SP 3

Python 2.7

Tkinter 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [py2exe](http://py2exe.org/) use `windows=['main.py']` instead of `console=['main.py']` when [creating your setup.py](http://py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step2)

For cx_Freeze this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11374527/2256700

Comment: Yep, for cx_Freeze, the key bit is `base = "Win32GUI"`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the answer anyone is looking for, but renaming the file extension from .py to .pyw under Python 3.4 and Win32 will effectively suppress the Python shell. You'll just get your Tk GUI window.

Answer (score 1):

Say your python script is called "myscript.py".

Create a file called `runme.vbs` containing code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN("myscript.py", 0, True)
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: And where do I place this file??

Comment: Place it in the same folder as your python file. You can then run the vbs file as though it's an EXE file.

Comment: What about platform compatibility? How many platforms is VBS compatible on?

Comment: I am going to distribute the application. SO I wanted a cross platform solution.