# Hide console window of python .py on windows

Tags: python, windows, console, python-3.5

I found this answers on Stackoverflow but nothing works for me

- [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)
- [Hiding the console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896062/hiding-the-console-window)
- [Hide console window with Tkinter and cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523867/hide-console-window-with-tkinter-and-cx-freeze/11374527#11374527)

I'm trying to hide console window, on windows at least. But with solutions above still I have window open

The only difference maybe I have to mark, I run python application with process from C# application, but as I understand it can't be a reason of some key different if I write all directives from the python code. Now I'm not sure how to figure out

Comment: From .NET you could set `CreateNoWindow` in the [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo). I don't understand why the support for `CreateProcess` [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863) is so lacking in .NET. They should support `DETACHED_PROCESS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `pythonw.exe` program as it won't open a terminal when ran.

Comment: Yes I'm going to mark it as answer, thanks, one question, I want use it for executable on user computer by exist environment variable path given from C#. So question is if there any different for this case, if `Process.Start("python.exe", pyscrpt);` or as you said `Process.Start("pythonw.exe", pyscrpt);`?

Comment: Assuming both are on your PATH environment variable, it should work fine.