# How can I make my GUI program(tkinter) work on computers with no python installed such that no console window appears?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Here's what I have done so far:
-I made a desktop search program/GUI using python and tkinter.

-Then I used py2exe to convert it to an exe.

-Now the software perfectly works on a machine(windows) without python installed, but the problem is that a creepy black window just appears along with the GUI when the .exe is opened.

Is there any way to make it look less creepy to an end user?

Comment: I think that this question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python). Hope this helps

Comment: I'm  a bit confused here. If I rename it with .pyw extension, will py2exe freeze it using pythonw.exe or something? And if the end user doesn't have python installed(thus no pythonw.exe), will it then make a difference?

Comment: I am going to check it, but I just asked for curiosity's sake.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension from .py to .pyw
(You must have Python installed for this to work.)

Duplicate:
[Hide console window with Tkinter and cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523867/hide-console-window-with-tkinter-and-cx-freeze)

Comment: well thanks! I'll try each of the solutions given in that answer and post here if it works :)

Comment: @Yugal If the solution worked for you, please consider marking it as the accepted solution to your problem.

Comment: how do I do that? Actually I'm new here :)

Answer (score 0):

Before converting your file to an **exe**, change the file extension (by renaming the file) from **.py to .pyw**.

'**.py**' files open with the console, whereas '**.pyw**' files open with no console window.